# Screen session inside of chroot does not show console output

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-screen, java, chroot

I have a chroot jail set up for a minecraft server to be managed via SSH by someone. The chroot is setup properly with proc and lib bind mounted to the / directory for the jail, chroot/usr folder containing a working installation of Java 17.0.7, and chroot/etc file has passwd/group in it. The chroot user is able to create screen sessions and use all of the tacks for screen, but when they attempt you run a command that outputs to console it gives this error `write error: Bad file descriptor`. Another symptom is when the minecraft server is launched inside the screen session by the chroot user it does not output anything to console, but it still starts and runs in the background without showing any evidence in console. If the chroot user is not in a screen session this error does not come up, it is only inside screen sessions.

In order to get screen to work in the chroot jail I had to bind mount run/screen and used the below set of commands for `dev/pts` and `dev/ptmx`:

```
mount -t devpts none "chroot/dev/pts" -o ptmxmode=0666,newinstance

ln -fs "pts/ptmx" "chroot/dev/ptmx"
```

If I launch the screen session as root and start the server or run commands none of these issues come up, so I am guessing it has something to do with stdout and stdin not existing in the chroot/dev folder. Any help or ideas would be appreciated, I can provide any additional info that may be important.